# Different way of rendering image in website

Tags: css, image

normally images in a website been rendered from top to bottom. But i found in another website that renders differently like [This site](https://squareup.com/register). How can i achieve this kind of cool effect to rending image in my website? Thanks.

Comment: I don't seem to understand what you mean?

Comment: ermm, you mean the fancy effects? That's called javascript...

Comment: This is called slide show using Javascript or one of its libraries such as Jquery.

Comment: @vallentin sory, what I mean is the way an image being render or load are different. normally when an image being load it appear from top to bottom, but in this site the image appear blurry first. i hope i made it clear.. this site shows the default way rendering the image http://www.zalora.co.id/

Comment: @ani where do you actually see that effect, because I don't see it anywhere on the website? the only "image effect" I see is the image slider fading between images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images on the website you mentioned are interlaced, which means that instead of initially loading the image at it's highest quality, it will first load the image at a very low quality, and then improve the quality of the image as it continues loading.

Here's a more detailed description of what interlaced photos are and how they work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps).

In order to achieve this with your own photos, you need to save them as interlaced photos. There should be an option for this in whichever image editor you chose to use.

An excellent article about interlaced photos: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/progressive-image-rendering.html. Scroll down a little bit for a gif that shows the difference between interlaced photos and photos that are loaded normally.

Comment: Many thanks @skimberk1 this is what i've been looking for..